# Fazer Link Direto com informações de pagina

Tags: php, javascript, arquivo, input, link

A alguns dias o Blogger mudou o sistema de compartilhamento de video deles.

Antes eles forneciam 1 link como esse

http://www.blogger.com/video-play.mp4?contentId=e1b5b436fa4803e1

Agora para ter o video eles colocaram um botão com a opção para fazer download do proprio.

ao clicar no link esse endereço é fornecido.

https://r2---sn-uphcg51pa-bg0l.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=d27fe9e70753e197&itag=18&source=blogger&requiressl=yes&mm=31&mn=sn-uphcg51pa-bg0l&ms=au&mv=m&pcm2cms=yes&pl=19&usequic=no&ei=EsLqW4LAGcK7qQW4mqXACw&susc=bl&mime=video/mp4&ratebypass=yes&dur=1430.093&lmt=1542109855233448&title=d27fe9e70753e197&ext=mp4&mt=1542111618&ip=179.54.158.53&ipbits=0&expire=1542154962&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,id,itag,source,requiressl,mm,mn,ms,mv,pcm2cms,pl,usequic,ei,susc,mime,ratebypass,dur,lmt,title,ext&signature=E85EBCD5D391F70A366AE951359DE9AD7F94DAEA3F561CEB30F3D4FB9C72D2B9.D550EE879059EEEB2E99F0E7E361F99D0C918A4E4B2230343421D5D19D058E01&key=us0

Usando o console fui pesquisar informações sobre como é feito o download.

e me apareceu isso

[image]

Usando a aba Network tive essas informações
[image]

[image]

Usando essas informações é possivel criar um link direto? que não precise ficar clicando no botão Download.

Apenas usando a Id do video? no caso é mediaId